# Want to create particular property value array from array

Tags: swift

Having array of employee object, called employees and now I want to create another array called filteremployees which is having only id and date of birth value. 
Using
 let filteremployees = employee.map({ $0.id}) 
I can get array which contains only id value but i want to have id as well dateOfBirth

```
class Employee {

    var id: Int
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var dateOfBirth: NSDate?

    init(id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to loop through the one array and add filtered data into another array?

Comment: @Jatin: One suggestion: `Employee` is a good candidate for being a `struct` here. And the properties are good candidates for being declared with `let` instead of `var`. Look a what *Abizern* has done with the `FilteredEmployee struct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let employees : [Employee] = ...
let list: [(Int, NSDate?)] = employees.map { ($0.id, $0.dateOfBirth) }
```

You must explicitly declare the type of `list` otherwise you get this error from the compiler

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

Tested with Xcode 7 Playground and Swift 2.0.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the same map method and returning a tuple of your expected values:

```
let filter employees: [(Int, NSDate?)] = employee.map({ ($0.id, $0.dateOfBirth) })
```

Alternatively, and I think this is a better solution, create a new value type and create that with only your required values

```
struct FilteredEmployee {
    let id: String
    let dateOfBirth: NSDate?

    init(employee: Employee) {
        id = employee.id
        dateOfBirth = employee.dateOfBirth
    }
}
```

And then you can map the initialiser over the array

```
    let filteremployees = employee.map { FilteredEmployee($0) }
```

Comment: I was trying the same solution, but your first block of code does not compile.